# Scheduled python code can't find module when run in Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, pip, cron

I'm trying to run a python script inside a Docker container every 2 minutes. To achieve this, I am using a cron job. When I run the Python script on the host machine, it executes perfectly, but inside the docker container I keep getting

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

The container builds perfectly fine, and the requirements are installed correctly according to the build log. My Dockerfile and cron job are as follows:

`Dockerfile`

```
    FROM python:latest 
    WORKDIR /root 
    COPY *.py . 
    COPY requirements.txt . 
    COPY cronjob.txt . 
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
    RUN apt update 
    RUN apt install cron -y 
    RUN crontab -l | { cat; cat cronjob.txt; } | crontab -
    ENV PYTHONPATH "$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages"
    CMD cron -f
```

`cronjob.txt`
`*/2 * * * * python3 runSync.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2`

`runSync.py`

```
import requests


def run_sync(network, ips, port, endpoint):
    for ip in ips:
        out = ""
        try:
            url = "http://" + network.format(ip=ip, port=port) + endpoint
            print("Resolving " + url + "...")
            res = requests.get(url)
            if res.status_code != 200:
                raise ValueError("Unexpected status code: {code}".format(code=res.status_code))
            print(res)
            print("Success!")
        # TODO: Better error handling
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            out = "Connection to server timed out."
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            out = "Unable to connect to server, please check internet connection."
            break
        except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
            out = "Malformed URL ", url, " please check and try again."
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            out = "Stopping..."
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            out = "Encountered error: \"{error}\"".format(error=e.args[0])
            break
    if out != "":
        return out
    else:
        return "Success"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    defaultNetwork = "192.168.33.{ip:n}:{port:n}"
    defaultPort = 8080
    defaultEndpoint = "/api/system/sync"
    defaultIPs = [29, 28, 12]
    out = run_sync(defaultNetwork, defaultIPs, defaultPort, defaultEndpoint)
    if out != "Success":
        print(out)
        exit(1)
    else:
        exit(0)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
requests==2.28.1
```

I've tried manually setting the PYTHONPATH (as seen in Dockerfile), as well as changing the application root to a couple of different options. I should be seeing the output of runSync.py in the docker logs, but instead I just get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`.

Comment: my bad. If you open a shell to the container and run the python script manually, does it work?

Comment: @DanielGarcia yes, it does! Seems like running it through cron may be the culprit....

Comment: @Darohan Agreed. Your issue was not the PYTHONPATH, though. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python:latest` image comes with both Python 3.9 (because Debian) and 3.11, and `cron` environment seems to use the former. Specifying the full path to the `python` executable in the `cronjob.txt` should fix it:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 runSync.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

or

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.11 runSync.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

You don't need to mess with the `PYTHONPATH` environment in the `Dockerfile` after this change.

Comment: This solution is simpler and probably more stable than @DanielGarcia's one from the thread above, so I'll mark it as the correct one, but I'll note for people looking at this in future that both seem to work just as well.

Comment: The other solution may have worked for `requests`, but it's not guaranteed for every package as it is basically asking Python 3.9 interpreter to use Python 3.11 packages downloaded from PyPI.

Comment: I agree, this is the right answer. I didn't try running the container, didn't know there were 2 python versions. I thought it was just cron being cron.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `/etc/crontab`, it has :

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You can put above setting in your cronjob.txt, then you don't have to use absolute path for python3.

Also, above setting make sure the PATH is the same on the command line and in crontab, this way it avoids problems for other commands as well.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for using cron

Try apscheduler, it's a python module for shceduling tasks:

https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/

short example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def some_job():
    print("Doing something...")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job,"interval",minutes=2)

try:
    scheduler.start()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```